# Javascript Ajax call returns same string multiple times from XML. How can this be avoided?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml, string, autofill

I have the following issue: When I make an Ajax call to give people an option to "autofill" a field, it offers the same string (as seen in the image below). The problem is, that the Ajax call uses an URL where the string appears in an XML multiple times.

For example, when calling

```
/tools/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Besucheranmeldung')/Items?&$filter=substringof('Aalen', FirmaNeu)&$select=FirmaNeu
```

the XML will look something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><feed xml:base="https://mylink/tools/_api/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns:georss="http://www.georss.org/georss" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><id>fbe3c761-2113-4be6-b8dd-599cf842df2f</id><title /><updated>2020-12-16T12:58:45Z</updated><entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'5d3a8bf8-7edf-4b7e-aab8-5df6cd818573')/Items(10891)</id><category term="SP.Data.BesucheranmeldungListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'5d3a8bf8-7edf-4b7e-aab8-5df6cd818573')/Items(10891)" /><title /><updated>2020-12-16T12:58:45Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:FirmaNeu>IGM Aalen</d:FirmaNeu></m:properties></content></entry><entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'5d3a8bf8-7edf-4b7e-aab8-5df6cd818573')/Items(10893)</id><category term="SP.Data.BesucheranmeldungListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'5d3a8bf8-7edf-4b7e-aab8-5df6cd818573')/Items(10893)" /><title /><updated>2020-12-16T12:58:45Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:FirmaNeu>'IGM Aalen</d:FirmaNeu></m:properties></content></entry><entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'5d3a8bf8-7edf-4b7e-aab8-5df6cd818573')/Items(10894)</id><category term="SP.Data.BesucheranmeldungListItem" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" href="Web/Lists(guid'5d3a8bf8-7edf-4b7e-aab8-5df6cd818573')/Items(10894)" /><title /><updated>2020-12-16T12:58:45Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:FirmaNeu>IGM Aalen</d:FirmaNeu></m:properties></content></entry><entry m:etag="&quot;2&quot;"><id>Web/Lists(guid'5d3a8bf8-7edf-4b7e-aab8-5df6cd818573')/Items(10895)</id><category term="SP.Data.BesucheranmeldungListItem"
```

[image]

I use the following code to get the dropdown:

```
var requestHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": NWF$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
};


function startAutoComplete(varTextBoxId, listname) {
    console.log("startAutoComplete called!");

    NWF$("#" + varTextBoxId).autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {

            var query = getQuery(request.term, listname);

            var testurl = "/tools/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/Items?&$filter=" + query;

            console.log("testurl: " + testurl);

            NWF$.ajax({

                url: "/tools/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/Items?&$filter=" + query,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("error:" + thrownError + "\n" + xhr.status);
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    response(NWF$.map(data.d.results, function (item) {


                        switch (listname) {
                            case "Besucheranmeldung":

                                return {
                                    label: item.FirmaNeu,
                                    value: item.FirmaNeu,
                                    id: item.FirmaNeu,
                                    listname: listname
                                }
                                break;

                        }
                        
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            

        },
        open: function () {
            NWF$(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            NWF$(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }
    });

}

function getQuery(requestStr, listname) {
    var retvalue = "";

    requestStr = encodeURIComponent(requestStr);

    switch (listname) {

        case "Besucheranmeldung":
            retvalue = "substringof('" + requestStr + "', FirmaNeu)" + "&$select=FirmaNeu";
            break;
    }
    
    // console.log("retvalue: " + retvalue);
    return retvalue;
    
}
```

How can this be avoided? Is there a way to make an if statement which checks whether the dropdown contains the same string twice to avoid letting it appear there multiple times?

When I do `console.log(data.d.results);`, I get the following:

[image]

Comment: When you log `data.d.results`, what does it contain?

Comment: Likely browser caching is causing your isssue.  Try adding a dummy cache-buster value like "&dt=" + new Date().valueOf() to the URL.  This will make every request have a unique time-stamp, and prevent the cached result from being returned.

Comment: @Tomalak I edited the post.

Comment: @WilliamWalseth I tried that out, but it didn't change anything, sorry.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text or code when you can post the actual code. Screenshots are useless. But it's obvious that the duplication is already in the data. Check the source list itself, or your way of querying it.

Comment: @Tomalak How do you expect people to post the "data.d.results" of the console here? Anyway, I found the answer here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/95594/how-to-group-distinct-values-from-a-list-using-odata-rest-api

Thank you for your help nonetheless

Comment: By encoding it as JSON and posting that here as plain text, would be one of the ways. The point is, screenshots of code are useless for anybody. They are neither searchable, nor can you copy them to develop or test a possible answer. Avoid screenshots of anything that is not strictly a graphics issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by changing the code:

```
var requestHeaders = {
    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "X-RequestDigest": NWF$("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
};


function startAutoComplete(varTextBoxId, listname) {
    console.log("startAutoComplete called!");

    NWF$("#" + varTextBoxId).autocomplete({

        source: function (request, response) {

            var query = getQuery(request.term, listname);

            NWF$.ajax({

                url: "/tools/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listname + "')/Items?&$filter=" + query,
                contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
                headers: requestHeaders,

                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    alert("error:" + thrownError + "\n" + xhr.status);
                },

                success: function (data) {
                    // console.log(data.d.results);
                    var firmaResults;
                    var firmen = [];
                    firmaResults = groupBy(data.d.results,'FirmaNeu');
                    // console.log(firmaResults);

                    for (var i = 0; i < firmaResults.length; i++ ){
                        firmen[i] = firmaResults[i];
                    }

                    var counter = -1;

                    response(NWF$.map(data.d.results, function (item) {


                        switch (listname) {
                            case "Besucheranmeldung":
                                counter++;
                                if (counter > firmaResults.length){
                                    return;
                                }
                                return {
                                    label: firmen[counter],
                                    value: firmen[counter],
                                    id: firmen[counter],
                                    listname: listname
                                }

                                break;
                        }

                    }));

                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2,
        select: function (event, ui) {


        },
        open: function () {
            NWF$(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
        },
        close: function () {
            NWF$(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
        }
    });
    
}

function getQuery(requestStr, listname) {
    var retvalue = "";

    requestStr = encodeURIComponent(requestStr);

    switch (listname) {

        case "Besucheranmeldung":
            retvalue = "substringof('" + requestStr + "', FirmaNeu)" + "&$select=FirmaNeu";
            break;
    }
    
    // console.log("retvalue: " + retvalue);
    return retvalue;
    
}


function groupBy(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        if ($.inArray(item[propertyName], result) == -1) {
            result.push(item[propertyName]);
        }
    });
    return result;
}
```